# Python - passing modified callback to dispatcher

Tags: python-2.7, callback, scrapy

[Scrapy](http://www.scrapy.org) application, but the question is really about the Python language - experts can probably answer this immediately without knowing the framework at all.

I've got a class called `CrawlWorker` that knows how to talk to so-called "spiders" - schedule their crawls, and manage their lifecycle.

There's a `TwistedRabbitClient` that has-one `CrawlWorker`. The  client only knows how to talk to the queue and hand off messages to the worker - it gets completed work back from the worker asynchronously by using the worker method `connect_to_scrape` below to connect to a signal emitted by a running spider:

```
def connect_to_scrape(self, callback):
        self._connect_to_signal(callback, signals.item_scraped)

def _connect_to_signal(self, callback, signal):
    if signal is signals.item_scraped:
        def _callback(item, response, sender, signal, spider):
            scrape_config = response.meta['scrape_config']
            delivery_tag = scrape_config.delivery_tag

            callback(item.to_dict(), delivery_tag)
    else:
        _callback = callback

    dispatcher.connect(_callback, signal=signal)
```

So the worker provides a layer of "work deserialization" for the Rabbit client, who doesn't know about spiders, responses, senders, signals, items (anything about the nature of the work itself) - only `dict`s that'll be published as JSON with their delivery tags.

So the callback below isn't registering properly (no errors either):

```
def publish(self, item, delivery_tag):
    self.log('item_scraped={0} {1}'.format(item, delivery_tag))

    publish_message = json.dumps(item)

    self._channel.basic_publish(exchange=self.publish_exchange,
                                routing_key=self.publish_key,
                                body=publish_message)

    self._channel.basic_ack(delivery_tag=delivery_tag)
```

But if I remove the `if` branch in `_connect_to_signal` and connect the callback directly (and modify `publish` to soak up all the unnecessary arguments), it works.

Anyone have any ideas why?

Comment: `But if I remove the if branch in _connect_to_signal and connect the callback directly ..., it works.` - What happens otherwise?

Comment: The callback isn't at all invoked when I expected it to be (as they are when I don't have the `if` branch), and no exceptions are raised.

Comment: `The callback isn't at all invoked` - How did you confirm this?

Comment: Logging. The callback has some lines that log to standard out. It also publishes to a queue, and that queue is empty.

Also, PyCharm breakpoints aren't stopping in the callback anymore.

Comment: `if signal is signals.item_scraped:` - What is `signal` and what is `signals.item_scraped`?

Comment: `signal` in this case is `signals.item_scraped` -  which is a singleton in another package that's created as 

    item_scraped = object()


I edited the question to put the public method closer to the private method - the client doesn't know a thing about the specific signal, the worker populates it itself in `connect_to_scrape`.

Comment: Did you check if the control flow enters the `if signal is signals.item_scraped:` block?

Comment: Yes, just stepped through it in the debugger. It goes into the declaration of `_callback`, then into `dispatcher.connect` - then into [PyDispatcher](http://pydispatcher.sourceforge.net/) land.

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured out why this wasn't working, by re-stating it in a more general context:

```
import functools

from scrapy.signalmanager import SignalManager


SIGNAL = object()


class Sender(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.signals = SignalManager(self)

    def wrap_receive(self, receive):
        @functools.wraps(receive)
        def wrapped_receive(message, data):
            message = message.replace('World', 'Victor')
            value = data['key']

            receive(message, value)

        return wrapped_receive

    def bind(self, receive):
        _receive = self.wrap_receive(receive)

        self.signals.connect(_receive, signal=SIGNAL,
                             sender=self, weak=False)

    def send(self):
        message = 'Hello, World!'
        data = {'key': 'value'}

        self.signals.send_catch_log(SIGNAL, message=message, data=data)


class Receiver(object):

    def __init__(self, sender):
        self.sender = sender
        self.sender.bind(self.receive)

    def receive(self, message, value):
        """Receive data from a Sender."""
        print 'Receiver received: {0} {1}.'.format(message, value)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sender = Sender()
    receiver = Receiver(sender)

    sender.send()
```

This works if and only if `weak=False`.

The basic problem is that when connecting to the signal, `weak=False` needs to be specified. Hopefully someone smarter than me can expound on why that's needed.